# This merchant is not enabled for Google Pay. [Android, React-Native]

Tags: android, react-native, android-pay, google-pay

i need to integrate android/google Pay in my app. used react-native-payments for integrate native payment wallet.

Sheet open in type os TEST mode but in release mode give error Like This merchant is not enabled for Google Pay.

already generate merchantId in Play store console and try to run app from beta testing.

how can i enable google pay?? i can't find.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
    android:value="true" />
```

in your AndroidManifest file in `<application>`

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Pay Integration Checklist](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist) explains that production access needs to be requested from Google:

> After you validate that you've fulfilled the exit criteria for each check above, click **Request production access** to begin the process of obtaining production access.

The button that takes you to the form to enable Google Pay production access is on that page. Make sure you've done everything from the checklist before you do so, since apps are subject to a manual review.